How to find the basis vector of a transformed frame?
I have a frame B that is rotated w.r.t to frame A about the z axis by 30 degrees clockwise and translated by [2, 0, 0]. Frame A is translated by [1, 0, 0] w.r.t to the world frame. The goal is to recover the basis vectors of frame B because I need to plot the coordinate frame in Python with Matplotlib. I can get the transformation matrices from frame A to frame B and from the world frame to frame A but I don't know how to calculate the basis vectors of frame B. I want to find the basis vector w.r.t to the world frame and additionally w.r.t to frame A but I confused on how to get there? Help and guidance would be greatly appreciated

Since we are dealing with translated frames, a basis vector of $B$ would be defined with respect to the world frame in terms of not only its vector components but also the coordinates of its origin.
Since $A$ is not rotated with respect to the world, the origin of $B$ is at $[3,0,0]$ in world coordinates.
The components of $B$ in either frame (translated $A$ or original world) are the columns of the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(30°) & \sin(30°) & 0 \\
-\sin(30°) & \cos(30°) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where, for the signs in front of the off-diagonal sine entries, we are relying on the convention that the clockwise rotation moves $X$ towards negative $Y$ values.
If you need to draw arrows where the starting and ending points are expressed in world coordinates, the common starting point is $[3,0,0]$ and the ending points are the columns of
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 + \cos(30°) & 3 + \sin(30°) & 3 \\
-\sin(30°) & \cos(30°) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
